# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 separated toolbars

Tags: sql-server-2012

In SQL Server Management Studio 2012, is there a way to get the toolbars separated, so there is space between them? I can do this with 2008 R2 by just dragging the toolbar handle. But in 2012, I can snap them to a different row, but if I just drag them apart, they always dock right next to each other. I find it convenient to have some space between them, with the left-most button of each one being my most-used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option close to what you need is to mark the control as "Begin a Group", to create a separator to the left of the control.

Open SSMS > Tools > Customize > Commands tab > under Toolbar select "Standard" > highlight "Activity Monitor" > click Modify Selection and you can (un)tick "Begin a group" and see how the toolbar changes. You could edit the Name to start with something like "__" for visual comfort (doesn't seem to take extra spaces).

Comment: Thanks, that's worth trying. I notice the left-most item in a toolbar doesn't let you begin a group, but maybe the name or a dummy entry might work.